# Form submission to specified url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, the url `/hashtags/:hashtag_name` shows all of the posts that have been tagged with the specified hashtag name. I want to add a search form on a static page that a user can type in something like `design` and on submit it redirects to `/hashtags/design` and shows all the post's with that hashtag. Can anyone shed some like on how to accomplish this??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have jQuery:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
  window.location.href = "/hashtags/" + e.target.value
})
```

Nice to have here: https://github.com/railsware/js-routes